# Initialize Components by String

Tags: reactjs

I have a menu that will display a component dynamically, I want to initialize my component via name. Is that even possible?

```
        var componentName = 'SomeOfComponent';
        ///Instead OF this
        switch(componentName)
        {
            case "componentName":
                return <StatementOfFaith  />;
        }

        //I want this 
        return <[componentName]/>
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have an object mapping to this components:

```
const Components = {
    name1 : ComponentA
    name2: ComponentB
}
```

And call it like this:

```
return <Components['name2'] />
```

Comment: It worked:)) Thanks Mam/Sir... Great help

   const Components = {
            name1 : <ComponentX />,
            name2 : <ComponentY />,
            name3 : <ComponentZ />
        }
     
            
          return  Components['name1'];

Comment: Glad to help. If the question was solved please accept the answer so that it can be closed. Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: hmm, although it works, your `Components` object is *not* a component, so treating as such where you use it is bad practice imo.

Comment: Components are just functions, there is nothing wrong in storing then in an object or array. You can just render an array of components in render for example. Eg: `return [<CompA />, <CompB />] `

Comment: I didn't say there was anything wrong with storing them in an array etc, it's that you are implying that your `Component` Object is a React component when you wrap it in jsx brackets. "Conceptually, components are like JavaScript functions. They accept arbitrary inputs (called “props”) and return React elements describing what should appear on the screen." https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: I'm  implying that the property named `nameA` is a component

Comment: yes, it's a dictionary of components* where can i access by key.